# Create custom interactive map

Tags: html, css

I want to create a simple "interactive" map, where there would be an image (the map) and some elements on it.
I'd like my elements to glow/open a pop-up when hover or click on it, or even open a new page.

My process would be to create a new div, add new elements on it with a position:absolute and place them with top/left/right/bottom... and add CSS hover proprieties to the elements.

But, I know this might not be the appropriate way to do it.

> My questions are :

1. Can I do that using only HTML/CSS ? Or should I start learning new
   programing languages ?
2. Is there any plugins or sites available for what I want to do ?

Comment: For a simple map that doesn't require zoom and pan the way you describe using HTML/CSS should be perfectly fine. Edit: If you do want to create a more advanced map, I'd suggest using the Google Maps API to create a custom map much like the interactive Los Santos map on IGN: http://www.ign.com/maps/gta-5/los-santos-blaine-county

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you use JavaScript with this for interactivity.

Check out the Google maps api. It can do what you are trying to do.

We have a helper plugin for maps api and jQuery for setting the markers on the map.
http://github.com/Lucien-Consulting/Google-Map-Marker.git

Those two suggestions will get you started. Just jump in and try it!